# How to setup AutoFac in .NET 7 Worker

Tags: azure-functions, autofac

Does anyone know the correct way to setup AutoFac in a .NET 7 worker process Azure Function?

I have this in program.cs

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder builder) =>
{
   // functionAppInitializer.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder);

    builder
        .AddApplicationInsights()
        .AddApplicationInsightsLogger();
})
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((builder) =>
{
    functionAppInitializer.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder);
})
.ConfigureServices((s) =>
{
    functionAppInitializer.ConfigureServicesOnly(s);
})
.Build();
```

ConfigureServicesOnly method just adds my services to the service collection

In the past I have code like below to setup AutoFac

```
//configure autofac
var container = new ContainerBuilder();
container.Populate(services);
return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());
```

How can I use this convention in the new setup method?

I know there is also a ConfigureContainer method but I dont know how to get the services into it?

Please note I am using .NET 7 not .NET Core 3.1

Paul

Answer (score -1):

Please check if below findings helps to solve the issue:

`Autofac` extension is supported for .NET 3 and .NET 7 Versions as checked in the NuGet Packages Sites [1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection) & [2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AzureFunctions#supportedframeworks-body-tab) and also for the .NET Stack Azure Function.

> I know there is also a ConfigureContainer method but I dont know how to get the services into it

[image]

I found that the code for using `ConfigureContainer` is same across all the .NET Core Versions and adding the services like **`applicationServices`**, **`Controllers as Services`** in the ConfigureContainer Method, found in this [Autofac Doc Section](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services). and Standard Services can be configured in `ConfigureServices` method with the help of `IServiceCollection` and registered providers.